# Async TCP Server / Client Approach

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, tcp

i am currently developing an async tcp client/server project.
Multiple clients will connect to the server (~100), and i am sending objects with a size up to 0.7mb.
I would like to send the data (binaryformatter serialized) parallel to all clients.
Therefore i wrote following code:

TCP Server:

```
    private Task _pending = Task.FromResult<bool>(true);
    /// <summary>
    /// Objekt senden
    /// </summary>
    public async void Send(object data)
    {
        var previousTask = _pending;
        _pending = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await previousTask;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            _serializer.Serialize(ms, data, Settings.Serialisation);
            if (Settings.UseCompression)
                ms = new MemoryStream(_compression.Compress(ms));
            if (Settings.Stream.AppendSignature)
                new MemoryStream(Settings.Stream.Signature).CopyTo(ms);
            Send(ms.ToArray());
            ms.Dispose();
        });
        await _pending;
    }

    public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                _clients.ForEach(c => c.Send(data));
            }
        }catch(System.Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex, "Error while sending data", this);
        }
    }
```

and here is my client handler send method

```
public void Send(byte[] data)
    {
        if (State != ConnectionState.Connected)
            return;

        try
        {
            _tcpsocket.SendAsync(CreateSendEventArgs(data));
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex, "Error on Send", this, LogLevel.Debug);
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
```

for some reason the sending method is not really parallel, the clients are receiving the data at a random time. I am guessing i am doing something wrong with this async/await stuff.

KR Manuel

Comment: You need to send all connected clients the same data, or you can work with each client individually?

Comment: normally i send the same data to all clients, but sometimes i need to send data to specific clients

Answer (score 1):

You are awaiting each send, why don't you await them all?

Some PSEUDO might help,.

```
public async Task Send(object data)
{
    var newTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        _serializer.Serialize(ms, data, Settings.Serialisation);
        if (Settings.UseCompression)
            ms = new MemoryStream(_compression.Compress(ms));
        if (Settings.Stream.AppendSignature)
            new MemoryStream(Settings.Stream.Signature).CopyTo(ms);
        Send(ms.ToArray());
        ms.Dispose();
    });
    return newTask;
}

public void Send(byte[] data)
{
    try
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Task[] tasks = _clients.Select(c => c.Send(data)).ToArray();
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }
    }catch(System.Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionHandler.HandleException(ex, "Error while sending data", this);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your send method you calling c.send(data) which is not returning a task as you see in my code above (clienthandler send method). the socket.SendAsync is not return a task for what reason ever?